# Numpy array slicing using colons

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to learn numpy array slicing.

But this is a syntax i cannot seem to understand.

What does

`a[:1]` do.

I ran it in python.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])
a = a.reshape(2,2,2,2)
a[:1]
```

**Output:**

```
array([[[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[13, 14],
        [15, 16]]])
```

Can someone explain to me the slicing and how it works. The documentation doesn't seem to answer this question.

Another question would be would there be a way to generate the a array using something like

`np.array(1:16)` or something like in python where

```
x = [x for x in range(16)]
```

Comment: I copied from notebook so I might have missed that line but let's assume it did

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The commas in slicing are to separate the various dimensions you may have. In your first example you are reshaping the data to have 4 dimensions each of length 2. This may be a little difficult to visualize so if you start with a 2D structure it might make more sense:

```
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4))
>>> a
    array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
           [12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> a[0]  # access the first "row" of data
    array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> a[0, 2]  # access the 3rd column (index 2) in the first row of the data
    2
```

If you want to access multiple values using slicing you can use the colon to express a range:

```
>>> a[:, 1]  # get the entire 2nd (index 1) column
    array([[1, 5, 9, 13]])
>>> a[1:3, -1]  # get the second and third elements from the last column
    array([ 7, 11])
>>> a[1:3, 1:3]  # get the data in the second and third rows and columns
    array([[ 5,  6],
           [ 9, 10]])
```

You can do steps too:

```
>>> a[::2, ::2]  # get every other element (column-wise and row-wise)
    array([[ 0,  2],
          [ 8, 10]])
```

Hope that helps. Once that makes more sense you can look in to stuff like adding dimensions by using `None` or `np.newaxis` or using the `...` ellipsis:

```
>>> a[:, None].shape
    (4, 1, 4)
```

You can find more here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 4):

It might pay to explore the `shape` and individual entries as we go along.

Let's start with

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])
>>> a.shape
(16, )
```

This is a one-dimensional array of length 16.

Now let's try

```
>>> a = a.reshape(2,2,2,2)
>>> a.shape
(2, 2, 2, 2)
```

It's a multi-dimensional array with 4 dimensions.

Let's see the 0, 1 element:

```
>>> a[0, 1]
array([[5, 6],
   [7, 8]])
```

Since there are two dimensions left, it's a matrix of two dimensions.

---

Now `a[:, 1]` says: take `a[i, 1` for all possible values of `i`:

```
>>> a[:, 1]
array([[[ 5,  6],
    [ 7,  8]],

   [[13, 14],
    [15, 16]]])
```

It gives you an array where the first item is `a[0, 1]`, and the second item is `a[1, 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second part of your question (generating arrays of sequential values) you can use [`np.arange(start, stop, step)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) or [`np.linspace(start, stop, num_elements)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html). Both of these return a numpy array with the corresponding range of values.